# Docker Compose: No such image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose up`,  I get this error:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/benson/Docker/HaproxyMy# docker-compose up
Recreating 950ddc308278_950ddc308278_950ddc308278_950ddc308278_950ddc308278_haproxymy_webb_1
Recreating 485800bdf3a1_485800bdf3a1_485800bdf3a1_485800bdf3a1_485800bdf3a1_haproxymy_webc_1
Recreating 2b3338d88716_2b3338d88716_2b3338d88716_2b3338d88716_2b3338d88716_haproxymy_weba_1

ERROR: for webb  No such image: sha256:15853e771e7ca3f5eecee38fcf97efd3ee164c1b66e2ef543d9985a04e78e099

ERROR: for webc  No such image: sha256:15853e771e7ca3f5eecee38fcf97efd3ee164c1b66e2ef543d9985a04e78e099

ERROR: for weba  No such image: sha256:15853e771e7ca3f5eecee38fcf97efd3ee164c1b66e2ef543d9985a04e78e099
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
weba:
    build: ./web
    expose:
        - 80

webb:
    build: ./web
    expose:
        - 80

webc:
    build: ./web
    expose:
        - 80


haproxy:

    image: haproxy:latest

    volumes:

        - ./haproxy:/haproxy-override
        - ./haproxy/haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:ro
    links:

        - weba
        - webb
        - webc
    ports:

        - "80:80"
        - "70:70"
    expose:

        - "80"
        - "70"
```

Answer (score 268, accepted):

The old cache caused this issue, I failed to run this command the first time and docker-compose already created images which I can't see from `docker images`.

Need to check from `docker-compose ps`, and remove all old images with this command `docker-compose rm`, then rebuild again.

Comment: Look at Shiva's answer too. Wonder why it took almost a year to improve on this one? Come on, SO!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43381147/8283848 this will do the magic perfectly ( for me)

Comment: might be good to mention that docker-compose rm is without a following parameter id of the image, unlike the case with docker rmi #id. Otherwise I could not remove an existing name of a docker-compose image which was exited and erased via ```docker  rmi 2d0c8d6058f4_myprojectcom_app_1```

Answer (score 138):

I encountered this error when using [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) on Windows.

A container seems to have gone rogue; `docker-compose rm --all` caused the whole shell to freeze and restarting Docker Machine didn't help either, the container still showed up when doing `docker-compose ps`.

#### The solution was to execute `docker-compose down`.

Comment: better way is remove only failing images with `docker-compose rm webb webc weba` and then pull or build new one

Comment: @OzzyCzech I'm sure that was useful in your situation. But in mine `docker-compose rm` froze my shell.

Comment: I didn't have freezing issue but `docker-compose rm --all` wasn't removing all images. docker-compose down fixed the issue. (Ubuntu 16)

Comment: Thank you @MatthiasBraun. It worked for me on ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 53):

To solve this issue

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-filename.yml down

docker-compose -f docker-compose-filename.yml up
```

To see all images

```
docker images -a
```

Comment: The issue is with missing images and as such `up` and `down` commands don't work. The correct answer is to use `docker-compose rm` to clear images and `build` -> `up` again.

Comment: Bhargav Sir, You need to do more research before downvoting a answer specially if you do not have enough experience with that technology. Or you can atleast see previous answers ( by Matthias Braun ) which is saying the same thing that docker-compose down will solve the issue. It has solved the issue for me also along with other people(mac - 10.11.5 ) ( docker - 17.03.1-ce ) .

Comment: He did mention using `rm` and also in a comment under his answer.

Comment: He is saying **rm** **froze** his shell and does not solve the problem for him.

Comment: This works better than `docker-compose rm`. Thank you!

Comment: Solved for me as well. Thanks

Answer (score 24):

Problem was solved for me by doing

```
docker-compose ps
```

finding the problematic container name and then (note running `docker` here)

```
docker rm <problematic container name>
```

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 18.04.4 and Docker version 19.03.6

I tried Yogesh Yadav's answer, but

> $ docker-compose -f docker-compose-filename.yml up

command froze my terminal on running 'current locks'.

I was able to solve it by listing the containers:

```
$ docker-compose ps
```

And removing the problematic containers one by one, running:

```
$ docker rm <name_of_the_problematic_container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Examples using weba, webb and webc like "[How to use Docker Compose to run complex multi container apps on your Raspberry Pi](http://blog.hypriot.com/post/docker-compose-nodejs-haproxy/)" suppose that you are building those images.

```
weba:
  build: .
  expose:
    - 80
```

Meaning you have (in `/home/benson/Docker/HaproxyMy`) a `Dockerfile` [like this one](https://github.com/hypriot/rpi-node-haproxy-example/blob/master/Dockerfile) which will be interpreted by the build . to build those images.

Comment: Thanks , I found  the root case,  The old cache cause this issue, Thx. I will write the steps below.

Answer (score 0):

our issue was low disk space on the *swarm worker*. resolved by freeing some space at `/var/lib/docker` on swarmworker node and redeploying.

Answer (score 0):

On Docker Desktop Mac, I was getting all kinds of "image not found" errors from docker and docker-compose, couldn't `docker-compose down` or `docker system prune` or `docker ps` or anything.

What I ended up doing was:

```
$ docker pull debian
$ docker tag debian $MISSING_IMAGE_NAME
$ docker system prune -a
```

and that seemed to get things going.

(Note that I was still getting "Error response from daemon: platform unknown not supported" until I ran the prune. Honestly, I just assumed that any data left in the daemon was suspect and needed to be flushed with prejudice.)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me!

```
docker-compose -f <replace with yml config file-name> down
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final command/answer based off the top answers

```
clear && docker-compose -f {my-file} down --remove-orphans && docker-compose -f {my-file} up --build --remove-orphans
```

replace `{my-file}` with the name/path of your docker compose file