# Learning NodeJS & MongoDB Docker compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a NodeJS project that uses MongoDB. I would like to run this service in a Docker container, but despite the many examples I have based my learning from, this will not work.

Here is my **/heimdall_jwt/Dockerfile**:

```
FROM node:9-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install pm2 -g
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["pm2-docker", "start", "process.json"]
```

And here is my **/heimdall_jwt/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
    # Define the services/containers to be run
services:
    myapp: #name of your service
        build: ./ # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "3000:3000" #specify ports forwarding
        links:
          - database # link this service to the database service
        volumes:
          - .:/usr/src/app
        depends_on:
          - database    
    database: # name of the service
       image: mongo # specify image to build container from
```

I tried running via:  **$docker-compose up --build**
which results in the mongo being build and starting.  Here is the condensed output:

```
Building myapp
Step 1/8 : FROM node:9-alpine
...
Step 4/8 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> befb91b1324c
...
Removing intermediate container 945eb0ad40d5
Successfully built b500f7ec9b89
Successfully tagged heimdalljwt_myapp:latest
Creating heimdalljwt_database_1 ...
Creating heimdalljwt_database_1 ... done
Creating heimdalljwt_myapp_1 ...
Creating heimdalljwt_myapp_1 ... done
Attaching to heimdalljwt_database_1, heimdalljwt_myapp_1
database_1  | 2017-11-25T21:15:39.001+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten]    building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
database_1  | 2017-11-25T21:15:39.002+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
database_1  | 2017-11-25T21:15:39.003+0000 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 3.4
database_1  | 2017-11-25T21:15:39.005+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall | Error: Cannot find module 'bcryptjs'
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:542:15)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:472:25)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/user/User.js:2:14)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/user/UserController.js:12:12)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
myapp_1     | 0|heimdall |     at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
myapp_1     | PM2        | App name:heimdall_app id:0 disconnected
```

I am uncertain what is going on here, but I am guessing that the dependencies are either not being installed, or not being copied into the working directory.  How

**UPDATED**
Modified from original posting as I still am struggling to get this to work.

Comment: you can find the similar issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454548/docker-compose-no-such-image

Comment: Thank you, that helped move it a long a bit, but I still am unable to actually get this thing running.  I updated the post with my observation.

Comment: that's because of missing packages, you have to make changes in heimdall_jwt dockerfile, install all the necessary packages before starting npm install

Comment: I don't see where my Dockerfile is incorrect, I create directories, copy the package.json to them and then run `npm install`.  does that not install the necessary packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should copy files **after** `npm install`. Right now you are installing dependencies and then copying over everything, so you are effectively canceling that install and you don't have dependencies.

In your Dockerfile you have:

```
...
RUN npm install
RUN npm install pm2 -g
COPY . /usr/src/app
...
```

It should be:

```
...
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install pm2 -g
...
```

Comment: I get this: Step 5/8 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in 39ee34e1ce11
npm ERR! Unexpected token } in JSON at position 124674

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-11-28T01_28_32_360Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'myapp' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1  but I cannot find that .log file anywhere to troubleshoot

Comment: Troubleshoot your package.json. Remove something that you think might be causing this and try again...

Comment: You got that error after changing the order of COPY and RUN npm install?

Comment: I got that after changing the COPY and RUN order.  I found the log file and am looking into it now

Comment: You should make sure that package.json is there. Maybe copy package.json after copying everything. Maybe that's causing the error...

Comment: I moved the COPY package.json to just before "RUN npm install" and get the same error.  I think it is something like 'at tryCatcher (/Users/me/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)' but I don't have a bluebird in my package.json

Comment: Try to remove `volumes` from docker-compose.yml

Comment: That bluebird is in your global node modules, not in your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159948/discussion-between-sonoerin-and-andrija).