# How to fix Docker error "hnsCall failed in Win32: An adapter was not found" when deploying service?

Tags: docker-swarm, docker-machine, docker-network, docker-for-windows, docker

I'm attempting to run a four-node swarm from my host machine, with my machine being the manager, and three Hyper-V VMs as worker nodes. 
I'm attempting to run a static web page as a service across all nodes, but keep receiving `hnsCall failed in Win32: An adapter was not found` error on my host machine, and `No such image` from the VMs (trying to pull the service image from private registry).
This happens when deploying a stack or using `service create`.
I can, however, run the static page via container instance and it works fine.

I followed [this guide](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part4/#localwin) to set up and create my VMs, which I suspect is where my problem arises.
The Virtual Switch that I created via the HyperV Virtual Switch Manager, named `thevswitch`, is both external and set on the correct adapter. I initialized a swarm using the IPv4 of my host machine under `thevswitch` for the `--advertise-addr` flag, and successfully joined the VMs as worker nodes to this IP, while using the driver. Docker doesn't seem to see the virtual switch I created regardless.

```
PS C:\Docker\swarm-test> docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:28:48 2019
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

```
PS C:\Docker\swarm-test> docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
3f4030aafa56        Default Switch      ics                 local
m1c2nzylf14x        ingress             overlay             swarm
168954d1275d        nat                 nat                 local
be3f092c32cb        none                null                local
```

```
PS C:\Docker\swarm-test> docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
4xiljuldm32avsxwo8o513uv5 *   ATLL000597          Ready               Active              Leader              18.09.2
w2ftfwt4oz00keswt6ztmq9ec     vm1                 Ready               Active                                  18.09.6
82vpc65ezml87sxhhx9mlvszk     vm2                 Ready               Active                                  18.09.6
lej0a3gabyi3qfta1f4le1f3s     vm3                 Ready               Active                                  18.09.6
```

```
PS C:\Docker\swarm-test> docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE     URL                       SWARM   DOCKER     ERRORS
vm1    -        hyperv   Running   tcp://10.195.12.68:2376           v18.09.6
vm2    -        hyperv   Running   tcp://10.195.12.69:2376           v18.09.6
vm3    -        hyperv   Running   tcp://10.195.12.75:2376           v18.09.6
```

Host ipconfig:

```
PS C:\Docker\swarm-test> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (thevswitch):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Int.CSDental.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e90f:a37:5f33:87de%29
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.195.12.87
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.195.12.1

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 10:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch) 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5de7:19c9:a701:b06a%65
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.55.33
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.240
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (nat) 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f173:8:f6e1:123c%73
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.26.192.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Host machine (manager):

```
PS C:\Docker\swarm-test> docker inspect ATLL000597
[
    {
        "ID": "4xiljuldm32avsxwo8o513uv5",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 23501
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2019-05-29T16:41:17.1544224Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2019-05-29T17:35:40.2375377Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Labels": {},
            "Role": "manager",
            "Availability": "active"
        },
        "Description": {
            "Hostname": "ATLL000597",
            "Platform": {
                "Architecture": "x86_64",
                "OS": "windows"
            },
            "Resources": {
                "NanoCPUs": 8000000000,
                "MemoryBytes": 16971313152
            },
            "Engine": {
                "EngineVersion": "18.09.2",
                "Plugins": [
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "awslogs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "etwlogs"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "fluentd"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "gelf"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "json-file"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "local"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "logentries"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "splunk"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Log",
                        "Name": "syslog"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "ics"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "l2bridge"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "l2tunnel"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "nat"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "null"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "overlay"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Network",
                        "Name": "transparent"
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "Volume",
                        "Name": "local"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "TLSInfo": {
                "TrustRoot": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIBazCCARCgAwIBAgIUew6Ov5cRAAXjR61XOWyX0l3evSYwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw\nEzERMA8GA1UEAxMIc3dhcm0tY2EwHhcNMTkwNTI5MTYzNjAwWhcNMzkwNTI0MTYz\nNjAwWjATMREwDwYDVQQDEwhzd2FybS1jYTBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEH\nA0IABHiJekXiApSizb5ctC5JJ0r1EBXvuN5iXMSe3VM/d9rvnjzFozY7VRgALhHb\nAP3wxnnsVPX29JC2ZUlv6//U0LSjQjBAMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBBjAPBgNVHRMB\nAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQWBBRUFwLEeWDMyZMC1QLrz1xhAyapuDAKBggqhkjO\nPQQDAgNJADBGAiEAqgyoSTtQxJ9RHnW2Zk7KsJthXSaoreN59vw+Ozp7XFACIQDB\n+tmtX3nGoeAf/np9j8oqvMNqApiPcxya8ToNSg/Otg==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n",
                "CertIssuerSubject": "MBMxETAPBgNVBAMTCHN3YXJtLWNh",
                "CertIssuerPublicKey": "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEeIl6ReIClKLNvly0LkknSvUQFe+43mJcxJ7dUz932u+ePMWjNjtVGAAuEdsA/fDGeexU9fb0kLZlSW/r/9TQtA=="
            }
        },
        "Status": {
            "State": "ready",
            "Addr": "10.195.12.87"
        },
        "ManagerStatus": {
            "Leader": true,
            "Reachability": "reachable",
            "Addr": "10.195.12.87:2377"
        }
    }
]
```

Just one of the VMs:

```
PS C:\Docker\swarm-test> docker-machine inspect vm1
{
    "ConfigVersion": 3,
    "Driver": {
        "IPAddress": "10.195.12.68",
        "MachineName": "vm1",
        "SSHUser": "docker",
        "SSHPort": 22,
        "SSHKeyPath": "C:\\Users\\19030430\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\vm1\\id_rsa",
        "StorePath": "C:\\Users\\19030430\\.docker\\machine",
        "SwarmMaster": false,
        "SwarmHost": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
        "SwarmDiscovery": "",
        "Boot2DockerURL": "",
        "VSwitch": "thevswitch",
        "DiskSize": 20000,
        "MemSize": 1024,
        "CPU": 1,
        "MacAddr": "",
        "VLanID": 0,
        "DisableDynamicMemory": false
    },
    "DriverName": "hyperv",
    "HostOptions": {
        "Driver": "",
        "Memory": 0,
        "Disk": 0,
        "EngineOptions": {
            "ArbitraryFlags": [],
            "Dns": null,
            "GraphDir": "",
            "Env": [],
            "Ipv6": false,
            "InsecureRegistry": [],
            "Labels": [],
            "LogLevel": "",
            "StorageDriver": "",
            "SelinuxEnabled": false,
            "TlsVerify": true,
            "RegistryMirror": [],
            "InstallURL": "https://get.docker.com"
        },
        "SwarmOptions": {
            "IsSwarm": false,
            "Address": "",
            "Discovery": "",
            "Agent": false,
            "Master": false,
            "Host": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
            "Image": "swarm:latest",
            "Strategy": "spread",
            "Heartbeat": 0,
            "Overcommit": 0,
            "ArbitraryFlags": [],
            "ArbitraryJoinFlags": [],
            "Env": null,
            "IsExperimental": false
        },
        "AuthOptions": {
            "CertDir": "C:\\Users\\19030430\\.docker\\machine\\certs",
            "CaCertPath": "C:\\Users\\19030430\\.docker\\machine\\certs\\ca.pem",
            "CaPrivateKeyPath": "C:\\Users\\19030430\\.docker\\machine\\certs\\ca-key.pem",
            "CaCertRemotePath": "",
            "ServerCertPath": "C:\\Users\\19030430\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\vm1\\server.pem",
            "ServerKeyPath": "C:\\Users\\19030430\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\vm1\\server-key.pem",
            "ClientKeyPath": "C:\\Users\\19030430\\.docker\\machine\\certs\\key.pem",
            "ServerCertRemotePath": "",
            "ServerKeyRemotePath": "",
            "ClientCertPath": "C:\\Users\\19030430\\.docker\\machine\\certs\\cert.pem",
            "ServerCertSANs": [],
            "StorePath": "C:\\Users\\19030430\\.docker\\machine\\machines\\vm1"
        }
    },
    "Name": "vm1"
}
```

```
PS C:\Docker\swarm-test> get-hnsnetwork


ActivityId             : F5EEF28D-7A66-410E-8F06-85417531C225
AdditionalParams       :
CurrentEndpointCount   : 0
Extensions             : {@{Id=E7C3B2F0-F3C5-48DF-AF2B-10FED6D72E7A; IsEnabled=False; Name=Microsoft Windows Filtering Platform}, @{Id=E9B59CFA-2BE1-4B21-828F-B6FBDBDDC017; IsEnabled=False; Name=Microsoft Azure VFP Switch Extension},
                         @{Id=EA24CD6C-D17A-4348-9190-09F0D5BE83DD; IsEnabled=True; Name=Microsoft NDIS Capture}}
Flags                  : 3
GatewayMac             : 00-15-5D-0C-C5-08
Health                 : @{AddressNotificationMissedCount=0; AddressNotificationSequenceNumber=5; InterfaceNotificationMissedCount=0; InterfaceNotificationSequenceNumber=0; LastErrorCode=0; LastUpdateTime=132036146558887527;
                         RouteNotificationMissedCount=0; RouteNotificationSequenceNumber=0}
ID                     : C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444
IPv6                   : False
IsolateSwitch          : True
LayeredOn              : 77DEBE34-C5AF-43EF-86C1-92F7CF9CD8EF
MacPools               : {@{EndMacAddress=00-15-5D-0C-CF-FF; StartMacAddress=00-15-5D-0C-C0-00}}
MaxConcurrentEndpoints : 0
Name                   : Default Switch
NatName                : ICS85DBD8A9-EEA6-4691-9FE4-901A4445B714
Policies               : {}
Resources              : @{AdditionalParams=; AllocationOrder=2; Allocators=System.Object[]; Health=; ID=F5EEF28D-7A66-410E-8F06-85417531C225; PortOperationTime=0; State=1; SwitchOperationTime=0; VfpOperationTime=0;
                         parentId=D841CDEC-707C-421C-BC2C-155F3F378A40}
State                  : 1
Subnets                : {@{AdditionalParams=; AddressPrefix=192.168.55.32/28; GatewayAddress=192.168.55.33; Health=; ID=F7DEEC46-10E5-448D-B890-D78D93E6D560; Policies=System.Object[]; State=0}}
SwitchGuid             : C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444
TotalEndpoints         : 0
Type                   : ICS
Version                : 38654705666

ActivityId             : 6589B251-E629-4942-847F-DEE47853D5B6
AdditionalParams       :
CurrentEndpointCount   : 0
Extensions             : {@{Id=E7C3B2F0-F3C5-48DF-AF2B-10FED6D72E7A; IsEnabled=False; Name=Microsoft Windows Filtering Platform}, @{Id=E9B59CFA-2BE1-4B21-828F-B6FBDBDDC017; IsEnabled=False; Name=Microsoft Azure VFP Switch Extension},
                         @{Id=EA24CD6C-D17A-4348-9190-09F0D5BE83DD; IsEnabled=True; Name=Microsoft NDIS Capture}}
Flags                  : 0
Health                 : @{LastErrorCode=0; LastUpdateTime=132036158099689062}
ID                     : 07E7CCC7-187E-457B-A577-1EAFB16E9731
IPv6                   : False
LayeredOn              : 9108D862-FE98-4FE4-8004-2C210074F964
MacPools               : {@{EndMacAddress=00-15-5D-B0-CF-FF; StartMacAddress=00-15-5D-B0-C0-00}}
MaxConcurrentEndpoints : 0
Name                   : thevswitch
Policies               : {}
Resources              : @{AdditionalParams=; AllocationOrder=0; Health=; ID=6589B251-E629-4942-847F-DEE47853D5B6; PortOperationTime=0; State=1; SwitchOperationTime=0; VfpOperationTime=0; parentId=CAEB6648-F50F-4C19-95D8-038C4E3B7346}
State                  : 1
TotalEndpoints         : 0
Type                   : Transparent
Version                : 38654705666

ActivityId             : 7F5DFDB2-6E7E-497E-A33E-5BE5655DA57E
AdditionalParams       :
CurrentEndpointCount   : 0
Extensions             : {@{Id=E7C3B2F0-F3C5-48DF-AF2B-10FED6D72E7A; IsEnabled=False; Name=Microsoft Windows Filtering Platform}, @{Id=E9B59CFA-2BE1-4B21-828F-B6FBDBDDC017; IsEnabled=False; Name=Microsoft Azure VFP Switch Extension},
                         @{Id=EA24CD6C-D17A-4348-9190-09F0D5BE83DD; IsEnabled=True; Name=Microsoft NDIS Capture}}
Flags                  : 0
Health                 : @{AddressNotificationMissedCount=0; AddressNotificationSequenceNumber=0; InterfaceNotificationMissedCount=0; InterfaceNotificationSequenceNumber=0; LastErrorCode=0; LastUpdateTime=132036143540255829;
                         RouteNotificationMissedCount=0; RouteNotificationSequenceNumber=0}
ID                     : B242C9F9-89C0-4867-B14A-8A175A5D0DDB
IPv6                   : False
LayeredOn              : 80208A97-455B-4273-B95A-1E73666C9C52
MacPools               : {@{EndMacAddress=00-15-5D-D9-8F-FF; StartMacAddress=00-15-5D-D9-80-00}}
MaxConcurrentEndpoints : 0
Name                   : nat
NatName                : ICSBC687A8B-1FC0-4F10-A614-68EA68A3E2EF
Policies               : {}
Resources              : @{AdditionalParams=; AllocationOrder=2; Allocators=System.Object[]; Health=; ID=7F5DFDB2-6E7E-497E-A33E-5BE5655DA57E; PortOperationTime=0; State=1; SwitchOperationTime=0; VfpOperationTime=0;
                         parentId=7507FF2E-F59E-4B2C-8194-DDA947C5B5AE}
State                  : 1
Subnets                : {@{AdditionalParams=; AddressPrefix=172.26.192.0/20; GatewayAddress=172.26.192.1; Health=; ID=B735AB8E-A2F9-4134-84BC-598A492F976A; Policies=System.Object[]; State=0}}
TotalEndpoints         : 0
Type                   : nat
Version                : 38654705666
```

Dockerfile:

```
version: "3"
services:
        Hello:
                image: registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0
                ports:
                        -"8888:80"
                deploy:
                        mode: global
```

```
PS C:\Docker\swarm-test> docker service ps test_Hello --no-trunc
ID                          NAME                                   IMAGE                                          NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE                     ERROR                                                               PORTS
27iw2nyi610g971bk0meeuf1h   test_Hello.82vpc65ezml87sxhhx9mlvszk   registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0   vm2                 Ready               Assigned less than a second ago                                                    
tw7ren3nakf0ukigjsqzrnkmf   test_Hello.w2ftfwt4oz00keswt6ztmq9ec   registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0   vm1                 Ready               Rejected less than a second ago   "No such image: registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0"
xmdrc9102s4qjtstakrvh3msx   test_Hello.4xiljuldm32avsxwo8o513uv5   registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0   ATLL000597          Ready               Rejected 1 second ago             "hnsCall failed in Win32: An adapter was not found. (0x803b0006)"
ezh203iv1ntj3w18wgqzdjceo   test_Hello.lej0a3gabyi3qfta1f4le1f3s   registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0   vm3                 Running             Rejected 4 seconds ago            "No such image: registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0"
n3n4nfevoadawuqlusfbspg34   test_Hello.82vpc65ezml87sxhhx9mlvszk   registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0   vm2                 Shutdown            Rejected 4 seconds ago            "No such image: registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0"
t46s5etkwgumoa6jp22au3nq5   test_Hello.w2ftfwt4oz00keswt6ztmq9ec   registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0   vm1                 Shutdown            Rejected 5 seconds ago            "No such image: registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0"
rxwqbg2wndz4cdxw71k1d5ore   test_Hello.4xiljuldm32avsxwo8o513uv5   registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0   ATLL000597          Shutdown            Rejected 6 seconds ago            "hnsCall failed in Win32: An adapter was not found. (0x803b0006)"
as92ats2qur5sr6e8lxflz71w   test_Hello.lej0a3gabyi3qfta1f4le1f3s   registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0   vm3                 Shutdown            Rejected 9 seconds ago            "No such image: registry.local:5000/wintest/swarm-test:2.0.0"
```

What catches my attention is that inspecting the VMs seems to show that they're not part of a swarm, but they are?

```
PS C:\Docker\swarm-test> docker-machine ssh vm1 "docker swarm init"
Error response from daemon: This node is already part of a swarm. Use "docker swarm leave" to leave this swarm and join another one.
exit status 1
```

Also, the fact that checking `Get-HNSNetwork` shows that `thevswitch` is a transparent network. From my understanding, the way I created the network should've made it show as either overlay (for the driver) or external. On a previous attempt to accomplish these tasks, I had another vswitch I had created in the exact same identical way, but that one showed up as private. I don't understand how following the same steps can produce two different, and both incorrect, results.

Here also is a screenshot of my Virtual Switch Manager:
[V-Switch Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPFO0.jpg)

I have read all kinds of documentation from Docker and Windows regarding networking, specifically overlay networking, and I feel pretty lost. From my understanding, this should be working, and all errors I've found online point back to the same docs. I have not seen anything that would make me think this can't be done either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: First time using Docker, trying to put together a successful PoC. I know that my `docker-compose.yml` is not pretty to look at. I've spent more time learning about networking with docker than I have been able to learn best practices.

Comment: Just a stupid question, but do you have the following ports open? `7946 TCP/UDP` for container network discovery and `4789 UDP` for the container ingress network. Also I found some similar discussions about this topic here https://github.com/docker/for-aws/issues/61 and here https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39191. And regarding the "No such image" issue I found this, perhaps it might help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454548/docker-compose-no-such-image. Other than that, I am learning about Docker too, and just was browsing Stack-overflow to learn a thing or two. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who is running into a similar issue:

The issue was NOT actually network related like these error messages implied.
The problem ACTUALLY ended up being that the swarm nodes (but not my host) were all using Linux containers and trying to pull a Windows-only image. They were silently throwing architecture errors -- I only found this out when I tried to pull my image directly from a node. The errors generated while deploying to the whole swarm were highly misleading.

I did not "fix" this per say. We ended up restructuring our entire solution around this fact, and the situation no longer applies.